# On the performance of an audio live streaming application

Tags: audio, web, streaming, low-level, broadcasting

I would like to develop an application that will allow a user to live streams audio from his computer and broadcast it through the network.

My main concern is the performance of this application. I want the quality of the sound to be preserved as its highest and I would like as few "delay" as possible.

Can I reach such a level of performance with web-based languages such as AJAX, NodeJS, or Ruby (Ruby on Rails?) or should I consider more low-level languages such as C/C++?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The performance of sound of the application is not affected so much by the language you choose. That level of performance is achieved by using the correct protocols to send the audio stream over the network. One common mistake is to use HTTP which user TCP protocol because is has a lot of certificates to be verified and this delay the information from streaming live. The best protocol which is used by all big stream companies like Facebook, Instagram, Skype, Lync is the UDP protocol which is super fast because of the minimum level of certificates to be checked.

The companies mentioned above uses different programming languages in order to build the streaming servers and get almost the same results so this is my opinion that the protocol makes the difference.

You can use Java if you want, I have friends that work for 8x8 one of the best companies of live streaming in the USA and they have used JAVA for building the servers and the clients.

Comment: So all the technologies like AJAX or NodeJS use HTTP protocols to communicate? I don't want to re-invent the wheel so do you know any good web based technologies that will allow me to use UDP protocols?

Comment: HTTP has requests that are implemented with UTD protocols and all the tecnologies you mentioned include http requests